# É possivel unir um formulário em C# a um projeto VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Tenho dois projetos distintos, um com apenas um formulário em C#, posso incorporar o formulário no meu projeto em VB.NET ?

Comment: Sim, pode. Mas não o código fonte do formulário. Você precisa compilar o projeto C# que possui o formulário e então referenciar o assembly gerado no seu projeto VB. Então você poderá usar este formulário no projeto VB assim como você usa qualquer outra classe do *.Net Framework* ou de qualquer biblioteca de terceiros.

Comment: Teria um link ou uma explicação de como se faz essa referencia? @Caffé

Answer (score 6, accepted):

São duas opções:

- Converter o código c# para vb.net, veja essa ferrament [Conversor C# para Vb.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)
- Como dito por Caffé, colocar o formulário C# em um projeto separado, e usar o formulário no projeto VB.NET.

Para abrir o formulário C# no VB.NET, se os dois projetos estiverem na mesma solução:

```
Dim  csharpfrm As New ProjetoCSharp.Form1
csharpfrm.Show()
```

Estou sem o Visual Studio no momento, mas para adicionar a referência faça o seguinte: No projeto com o formulário C#, clique em projeto >> opções, e altere o tipo de projeto para biblioteca dinâmica.

Compile o projeto (Build, build solution, não sei como fica em português).

Em seguida, no projeto VB, no explorador de soluções, clique com o botão direito no projeto, adicionar, referências, e encontre o arquivo .dll na pasta do projeto C#, subpasta bin\release.

Comment: Mais informações aqui, mas está em inglês. Se for problema vou atualizando a resposta: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?270506-How-to-call-C-form-from-a-VB.NET-form

Comment: Vou testar hoje a noite, obrigado @RSinohara.

Answer (score 2):

Crie um projeto na mesma solução em C# e outro em VB, no do C# coloca o seu projeto, quando for usar esse projeto C# em VB, referencie ele no seu projeto.